# In win32 GUI programing with C++, How can I add a expanding button in the TreeViewCtrl before the root item?

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, treeview, wtl

1. In the C++ 、Win32、TreeCtrl, how can I add a expanding button before the root TVITEM, like add a expanding button before "United States".
   I'm sorry I can't post a image. So I try draw it blow.

   TreeViewCtrl

   ---

   ```
   |  United States           |
   |     - Pennsylvania       |
   |         Altoona          |
   |         Harrisburg       |
   |     + Washington         |
   ```

Comment: So you want to add a new node at higher level that United States or same level?

Comment: I have tried add a node at the same level, It doesn't work. I want to add a button at the root. What you said is a choice, but is there any way I can add a button at the root item?

Comment: I don't think you can, there is always only one root, what you want to do sounds like adding a new sibling node to United States which implies you really should have a root node called countries or similar, you could create a new tree ctrl and add the US and children plus your new item

Comment: Can I add a anonymous root node that can't be seen.

Comment: I find someone did it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/770/CShellTreeCtrl

Comment: Yes that would probably work, give it a go and if you have success please post what you did

Comment: Yes, I make it. I add a flag |TVS_LINESATROOT| when I create the TreeView window:
DWORD dwStyle = TVS_LINESATROOT | TVS_HASBUTTONS | TVS_HASLINES

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP VERY MUCH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some MSDN pages on the different styles you may want to achieve: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760013.aspx and also this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b17bescz.aspx

MSDN states that

> TVS_LINESATROOT
>
> Uses lines to link items at the root of the tree-view control. This
>   value is ignored if TVS_HASLINES is not also specified.